# I cannot get a Facebook embed to center

Tags: html

I am trying to center a Facebook embed but it won't center. Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

I've tried `align-content: center;` , `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;` , and adding `<center></center>` which did move it more into the center but it's still left leaning.

Here's the full code below

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fhttps://www.facebook.com/Benchwarmers-Eatery-Sports-Lounge-216023751752995/ID&width=600&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=true&header=true&height=435" scrolling="yes" style="border:black; overflow:hidden; width:900px; height:730px; background: black; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; " allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Facebook plugin's code (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/) is different. Check **Adaptive Width** section. You cannot go beyond 500px wide.

Comment: Because you mentioned using it, note that the `<center>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for 10 years or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use flex for this!

```css
div{
width:75vw;
height:100vh;
margin:0 auto;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}



body,html{
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fhttps://www.facebook.com/Benchwarmers-Eatery-Sports-Lounge-216023751752995/ID&width=600&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=true&header=true&height=435" scrolling="yes" style="border:black; overflow:hidden; width:75vw; height:75vh; background: black; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; " allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```